# how to add the word chapter to a fancy style?

Tags: sectioning

[image]

Dears
i am using a fancy style in my document, however i would like to add the word chapter to the number of chapter (see the picture bellow). how can i do that ?

Comment: Could you please add a minimal working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `titlesec`package (http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)

This should do the job :

```
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
  { \raggedleft
  \vspace{1pc}%
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} {\Huge\thechapter}}
  {1pc}
  {
  \raggedleft \Huge}
```

Comment: it doesn't work ERROR: Paragraph ended before \ttl@format@ii was complete.

Comment: The new code does what you need, sorry

Comment: yes, it works thank you. but it change font style , anyway , thanks so much, i'll use it.

Comment: I'm sorry, just drop the `\sffamily` and it would go to standard font.